# How do you implement deref on a generic type containing a trait in rust?

Tags: rust

It would be rather convenient to be able to use Deref to generate a &TraitType from a generic container, rather than calling instance.as_ref(). ie:

```
(*my_container).do_thing();
```

vs.

```
my_container.as_ref().do_thing();
```

To do this I tried to implement Deref on the container type, but I get this error:

```
<anon>:9:28: 9:29 error: expected a reference to a trait [E0172]
<anon>:9 impl<T> Deref for HasTrait<T + Send> {
```

From:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

trait Foo {}

struct HasTrait<T> {
  data:Box<T>
}

impl<T> Deref for HasTrait<T + Send> {
  type Target = T;
  fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {
    return self.as_ref();
  }
}

struct IsFoo;
unsafe impl Send for IsFoo {}
impl Foo for IsFoo {}


fn main() {
  let is_foo = IsFoo;
  let foo:Box<Foo> = box is_foo as Box<Foo>;
  let has_foo = HasTrait { data: foo };
  let foo_ref:&Foo = *has_foo; 
}
```

I've tried using ?Sized to increase the bounds of T to allow traits, but it didn't seem to help?

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

struct HasTrait<T: ?Sized> {
    data: Box<T>
}

impl<T: ?Sized> HasTrait<T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T {
        &*self.data
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Deref for HasTrait<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {  // '
        self.as_ref()
    }
}

trait Foo {}
struct IsFoo;
impl Foo for IsFoo {}

fn main() {
    let is_foo = IsFoo;
    let foo: Box<Foo> = box is_foo as Box<Foo>;
    let has_foo = HasTrait { data: foo };
    let foo_ref: &Foo = &*has_foo; 
}
```

Basically, your problem wasn't really connected with sizedness. It's just that `HasTrait<T + Send>` here:

```
impl<T> Deref<T> for HasTrait<T + Send>
```

is meaningless. `T` can be arbitrary type, and something like `u64 + Send` does not make sense. Consequently, I'm afraid, you won't be able to constrain `HasTrait` to contain *only* traits and *only* for those types which are `Send`. There is just no syntax for that, and I'm pretty sure the type system does not support it.