# Implementing Deref on a struct that owns a boxed trait

Tags: rust

I'd like to implement `Deref` and `DefrefMut` on a struct that owns a boxed trait, e.g.:

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

trait Quack {
    fn quack(&self);
}

struct QuackWrap {
    value: Box<Quack>
}

impl Deref for QuackWrap {
    type Target = Box<Quack>;

    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Box<Quack> {
        &self.value
    }
}

impl DerefMut for QuackWrap {
    fn deref_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Box<Quack> {
        &mut self.value
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
src/main.rs:14:5: 16:6 error: method `deref` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter 'a, found concrete lifetime [E0053]
src/main.rs:14     fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Box<Quack> {
src/main.rs:15         &self.value
src/main.rs:16     }
src/main.rs:20:5: 22:6 error: method `deref_mut` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter 'a, found concrete lifetime [E0053]
src/main.rs:20     fn deref_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Box<Quack> {
src/main.rs:21         &mut self.value
src/main.rs:22     }
```

If I replace `Box<Quack>` with `Box<String>` (or a similar type), it works. The problem is that `Quack` is a trait. But I'm not sure why that generated the error message it did. Any ideas?

My question is similar to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836444/how-do-you-implement-deref-on-a-generic-type-containing-a-trait-in-rust), but not quite the same. In that question, the struct has a type parameter with the trait as a constraint. Whereas in my question, there is no type parameter.

I don't want to confuse the issues, but there's a good reason that I need `Box<Quack>` in my application. I.e. I can't replace `Quack` with a type parameter. In case you care, the reason is [discussed further in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657436/traits-in-algebraic-data-types/30672566#30672566).

Comment: `type Target = Box<Quack>;` is `type Target = Box<Quack + 'static>;`, and `&'a Box<Quack>` is `&'a Box<Quack + 'a>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, add more lifetime annotations:

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

trait Quack {
    fn quack(&self);
}

struct QuackWrap<'b> {
    value: Box<Quack + 'b>
}

impl<'b> Deref for QuackWrap<'b>{
    type Target = Box<Quack + 'b>;

    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Box<Quack + 'b> {
        &self.value
    }
}

impl<'b> DerefMut for QuackWrap<'b> {
    fn deref_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Box<Quack + 'b> {
        &mut self.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, this helps because `struct QuackWrap { value: Box<Quack> }` is equivalent to `struct QuackWrap { value: Box<Quack + 'static> }`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know precisely which implicit lifetime was being added where, so I left my answer as just the fix. Answering why this broke in the first place is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Brian's answer and Shepmaster's explanation, I updated my code as follow. I also simplified the `QuackWrap` struct. (That wasn't strictly necessary, but it's arguably better style than what I was doing before.)

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

trait Quack {
    fn quack(&self);
}

struct QuackWrap(Box<Quack>);

impl Deref for QuackWrap {
    type Target = Box<Quack + 'static>;

    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Box<Quack + 'static> {
        let QuackWrap(ref v) = *self;
        v
    }
}

impl DerefMut for QuackWrap {
    fn deref_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Box<Quack + 'static> {
        let QuackWrap(ref mut v) = *self;
        v
    }
}
```

There may be a more concise way to destructure `QuackWrap` in the `deref` and `deref_mut` implementations. Some of those more obscure syntax rules elude me. But for now this is fine.

Comment: *There may be a more concise way ...* — Newtypes (and all tuple structs) offer positional accessors. Here's a [slightly smaller example](http://is.gd/Q6weUR)